# can not longer login during registration because of condition

Tags: php, function, conditional-statements, avatar

On my application users can upload avatars. They are not obliged to upload an avatar so I used a condition to check if users uploaded an avatar. But when I use this condition during the registration users can no longer log in to the application but I retrieve the data in my database. Before this condition registering and loggin in at the same time was no issue...

```
    if (empty($_FILES['upload']['name'])) {
                    $user->PPName = "";
                $user->PPNewName = "";
                $user->Register();
            }

            else {

                 $PPNewName = time() . $_FILES['upload']['name'];
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], "uploads/" . $PPNewName);
   $user->PPName  = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['name']);
   $user->PPNewName = $PPNewName;
   $user->Register();
            }
```

function (register and loggin in at the same time)

```
public function Register()
        {
            // register, salt gebruiken voor het beveiligen van het wachtwoord.
            $salt = "ab4p73wo5n3ig247xb1w9r";
            $db = new Db();
            // gegevens invoeren in de databank
            $insert = "INSERT INTO tblusers (
                          name,
                          email,
                          password,
                          surname,
                          avatar,
                          status,
                          current_challenge_id,
                          feeling

                      ) VALUES (
                          '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_sName) . "',
                          '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_sEmail) . "',
                          '". $db->conn->real_escape_string(md5($this->m_sPassword . $salt)) . "',
                           '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_sSurname) . "',
                          '" . $db -> conn -> real_escape_string($this -> m_sPPNewName) . "',
                              '" . $db -> conn -> real_escape_string("user") . "',
                               '" . $db -> conn -> real_escape_string("1") . "',
                               '" . $db -> conn -> real_escape_string("goed") . "'

                      )";
            $select = "SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE email = '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($this->Email) . "';";
            $result = $db->conn->query($select);
            //echo $result;
            if($result->num_rows == 0)
            {
                $db->conn->query($insert);
                //session_start();
                // Inloggen, name in session meegeven, exception tonen die weergeeft dat je bent geregistreerd
                $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                $_SESSION["name"] = $this->Name;
                $_SESSION["email"] = $this->Email;
                //throw new Exception("Signed up!");
                header("Location: challenge.php?challenge_id=1" );
            }

            Else {
                // Bij eerder gebruikte email
                throw new Exception("I'm sorry, your e-mailadres already exist");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Note: It looks like your are mixing `mysql_*` functions with other database connectors. Make sure you only use one type of database connector or you will get unexpected results. And the `mysql_*` functions are becoming deprecated and will be removed from future versions of PHP. You should not use them anymore.

Comment: Like Gerald stated above, you should really be using PDO for your data layer access. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 3):

Don't insert a default image, you'll waste space. Instead, you manage that in your clients at the time of displaying the avatar: you either send the avatar stored in DB or a URL to the default avatar.

Comment: hmm that's interesting :) but at this moment there is always a number in the db... so that's also a waste of space...

Answer (score 0):

The typical pattern for this need is to store and show the upload, *if there is one*, otherwise to just *show* a default.

So to implement that pattern: In your registration code, wrap the PPName fields in a conditional:

```
if (array_key_exists('upload', $_FILES)) {
   $PPNewName = time() . $_FILES['upload']['name'];
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], "uploads/" . $PPNewName);
   $user->PPName  = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['upload']['name']);
   $user->PPNewName = $PPNewName;
}
```

Ensure that your database schema allows for `PPName` and `PPNewName` to be `null`.

Then in your display code, do something like:

```
printf('<img src="%s" />', (isset($user->PPName) ? "uploads/{$user->PPNewName}" : 'default.png'));
```

This approach has the side benefit of allowing you to easily change the default image and have it immediately appear for all users without avatars.  There might be legitimate reason to store the default (like if you use the image to reserve a user's "spot" in the filesystem), but those cases are more rare.

Comment: I see where you are going to but it keeps storing the number with the given condition

Comment: You will need to update all your model code to handle an optional image, as well.

Comment: I created a new check to see if something is filled in but now I can not longer login after the registration... Before this condition it worked well. I updated the code